# Can the first difference of a time series follow a random walk?

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, expected-value, random-walk

I have a time series in levels, say $X_t$ and a variance-ratio test suggests that it does not follow a random walk.
Now I differenced the time series once and the variance-ratio test suggests that the first difference follows a random walk.

Can I just do that and calculate the expected value of $X_{t+1}$ as below?
\begin{align}
\Delta X_t \approx \Delta X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t &\iff X_t \approx 2 X_{t-1}-X_{t-2}+\varepsilon_t  \\[8pt]
 &\ \implies E[X_{t+1}| t] = X_t + \Delta X_{t-1}
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. I have suggested an edit to your question to improve the formatting of the formula, please check whether the adoption is correct.

Comment: There are time-series where the second difference is a stationary process.  Whether your data meets this is an empirical question